# UWP - MVVM - value not updated when calculated propoerty value changes

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, calculated-field

I'm developping a UWP app based of MVVM Pattern.

I Created a View Bound to a Parent ViewModel. 
Parent View Model Contains a Child ViewModel Property

Child ViewModel contains some informations, especially "NumberOfDays" and "AmountPerDay"

Parent ViewModel Contains its own properties, especially "DiscountAmount" and "TravellingExpenseAmount". 
Parent ViewModel Contains also calculated properties : 
    - TotalHT = (NumberOfDays * AmountPerDay) - DiscountAmount + TravellingExpenseAmount

this property is bound to "Total avant Taxes" in the screenshot

Notice that calculation is based on properties from the two ViewModels.

The problem is the following : 
- When I update properties from Parent ViewModel (DiscountAmount or TravellingExpenseAmount), TotalHT calculation property change is raised and textbox value is updated
- When I update properties from ChildViewModel (NumberofDays or AmountPerDay), Nothing happens even if, from the child ViewModel, i manually RaisePropoertyChange the parent Calculated propoerty (RaisePropertyChange("Calculated Property")).

[image]

All ViewModels implement INotifiedPropertychange(MVVM light toolkit).

Update : It seems that only properties made from the Two ViewModels are not updated correctly

Do you have any idea about a solution ??

Update : 
To be more precise, I updated my code to figure out my problem based on Anton comments (thanks to him ;-) )

I replaced the calculated property by a "writable" Property as the following :

```
private string totalBeforTaxes3 = 0.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    public string TotalBeforeTaxes3
    {
        get => totalBeforTaxes3;
        set => Set(() => TotalBeforeTaxes3, ref totalBeforTaxes3, value, true);
    }
```

I Set a Default Value to 0.

I also created a method to update the value and force RaisePropertyChanged (even if it's useless due to the fact that the Set() method already does it. here is the method code :

```
public void CalculateTotalBeforeTaxes()
    {
        TotalBeforeTaxes3 = (Double.Parse(Details.TotalHT, NumberStyles.Currency) - Double.Parse(DiscountAmount, NumberStyles.Currency) + Double.Parse(TravellingExpensesAmount, NumberStyles.Currency)).ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        RaisePropertyChanged("TotalBeforeTaxes3");
    }
```

Now when I Open the Page I the textbox value is O€ and never get updated. Each time I update a value which is part of calculation, CalculateTotalBeforeTaxes() is called and RaisePropertyChanged is Called without any error.

Another information is that ChildViewModel is not initialized in the ParentViewModel Constructor, but after (due to ViewModelLocator constraint). Do you think it could have some impacts ??

by advance thank you

Answer (score 0):

For a value to update, a trigger has to occur. In this case the trigger does not jump and therefore the value in the parent will never be recalculated.

You have to watch if one of the child controls throw the event and analyze them. Here are two solutions: schedule the entire event management process. Perhaps there is a more beautiful solution using XAML, but I have solved this case by managing the events manually.

When we create a child, the parent subscribes to its PropertyChanged events (PropertyChangedEventHandler). We then in the parent will receive the PropertyChangedEventArgs argument in which we have PropertyName. If the PropertyName is what we want - we recalculate the TOTAL in the parent VM.

Comment: Hi Anton nd thank you for your answer. when you tell "we recalculate the TOTAL in the parent VM", you mean call a raispropertychanged("Calculatedproperty") ?

Comment: When you receive event and catch it, you do it in special method/function. Like click event:
mouse.Click += mouse_click;

mouse_click(x args) {
// check args
do anything
} If the Calculated property in your get {return make calculation} is possible simple elevate PropertyChange to the View with name of property. But if Calculation has attribute already calculed value, you need first make calculation and then call to the PropertyChange to notificate to the View.